# Asymptotics of "heat" semigroup

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Consider a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary. Consider a second order elliptic operator $L$ on $L^2(\Omega)$, defined by either the Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions. Consider the semigroup $e^{tL}$, which is $L^2$-contractive by the Hille-Yosida theorem. Is it true that $e^{tL}f \to f$ as $t \to 0$ pointwise almost everywhere?

Comment: What are you assuming about $f$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Apriori I would want $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, if such a result is possible.

Comment: If $f \in L^2$ then $f$ is not well defined pointwise, so asking for pointwise convergence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Presumably it should be pointwise almost everywhere.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks, that's what I had in mind, should have been more precise.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry about that, edited as per Robert Israel's comments.

Comment: I think this follows from the arguments of Stein in http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=131517 .

Comment: For any sequence $t_n\searrow 0$ there exists  a subsequence $(t_{n_k})$ such that $e^{t_{n_k} L} f\to f$  a.e.

Comment: @TerryTao Can one say something when $f \in L^1(\Omega)$? Thanks!

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Can one say something when $f \in L^1(\Omega)$? Thanks!